# with my activex control IE process not quit after close window/pages

Tags: qt, activex

I am building an activex dll with Qt. I subclass `QAxFactory` to create the exported class object and use singleton pattern.

```
//MyFactory is subclass of QAxFactory
//MyClass is the exported class for com container to use
QObject *MyFactory::createObject(const QString &key)
{
    return MyClass::getInstance();
}
```

Here is the problem:

After refresh the IE page several times, then close the IE page/window, the exported class `MyClass`'s deconstruction gets called immediately, but `MyFactory`'s deconstruction not. And in windows task manager, the iexplorer process does not quit. After about 30~50 seconds, the iexplorer process quit and `MyFactory`'s deconstruction gets called.

I guess this is because my code did not clear some resources correctly, but I could not found what resource.

Is there a way I can debug this problem? Thanks in advance!

**update 1**
It looks like event handler did not get released properly in JS. Following is the event handler functions in js.

```
function MyClassObj::eventHandler()
{
    console.log("event fired");
}
```

How do I release the handler properly when page get refreshed or closed?

**update 2**
After struggling for days, I got some updates: If I distribute this activex control as in-process(dll), IE process will wait for about 1 minute to quit after close. But if I use it as out-process(exe), IE will quit immediately after close.
I tried with Qt offical examples, it is the same.
Still not sure whether this is normal or not.